# Get Emails of friends in Google plus api

Tags: php, email, google-plus, guzzle, google-php-sdk

I want to get the emails of my authorized user.
Currently i am only able to get their details like name and gender but unable to get their emails.
Here is the process i am following.

- Ask user to login from client side and generate a code
- send that code to my server which generates access token.

  $accessTokenResponse = $client->request('POST', 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', [
              'form_params' => $params
          ]);
- After i get access token i call the following api to get their friend list

  $profileResponse1 = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible', [
              'headers' => array('Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken['access_token'])
          ]);

Now i have the users google id but how to get their emails?

Answer (score -1):

You have add scope email while building login url. In case of google-php-api like this `$client->addScope("email");`